# Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Tags: upstart, 17.04

I have `upstart` installed:

```
$ sudo apt install upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcgmanager0 libnih-dbus1
Suggested packages:
  graphviz upstart-monitor
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libcgmanager0 libnih-dbus1 upstart
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 0 to remove and 31 not to upgrade.
Need to get 443 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,925 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libnih-dbus1 amd64 1.0.3-6ubuntu1 [14.1 kB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libcgmanager0 amd64 0.41-2 [35.0 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 upstart amd64 1.13.2-0ubuntu35 [394 kB]
Fetched 443 kB in 3s (135 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package libnih-dbus1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 215072 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnih-dbus1_1.0.3-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnih-dbus1:amd64 (1.0.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgmanager0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgmanager0_0.41-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcgmanager0:amd64 (0.41-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package upstart.
Preparing to unpack .../upstart_1.13.2-0ubuntu35_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking upstart (1.13.2-0ubuntu35) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.10-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libnih-dbus1:amd64 (1.0.3-6ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libcgmanager0:amd64 (0.41-2) ...
Setting up upstart (1.13.2-0ubuntu35) ...
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-21-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-20-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-9ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.10-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

But why do I get this error:

```
$ sudo initctl list
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

All I want to do is to deploy my django app following this [guide](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2015/11/python-27-django-apache-and-gunicorn-on.html).

I am on Ubuntu 17.04

Any ideas?

Comment: Whey are you following a guide for **CentOS 6.5** if you are running **Ubuntu 17.04**? They are significantly different - in particular, Ubuntu 17.04 uses `systemd` not `upstart`

Comment: ...and a rather ancient guide. Much has changed in two years.

Comment: Change that Upstart script to Systemd service file and it should work

Comment: @George i have tried ` Systemd` but i get 503 error...

Comment: @George i am not sure but you can see my question here that i just opened https://askubuntu.com/questions/916970/403-forbidden-for-django-gunicorn-systemd-apache