# 403 forbidden for django + gunicorn + systemd + apache?

Tags: apache2, systemd, django

I have followed [this](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#systemd) guide and [this](https://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/30/how-to-setup-apache-with-gunicorn/) to deploy my django with guniconrn and apache.

But I dont quite get what [this](https://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/30/how-to-setup-apache-with-gunicorn/) guide it says:

> (You still need to specify Alias and  for the static and
>   media files, in addition to the above.)

But anyway these are all my config. My django app is at `/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp`

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/pid
User=lau
Group=lau
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/pid   \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn/socket helloapp.wsgi
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn/socket

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

/etc/tmpfiles.d/gunicorn.conf:

```
d /run/gunicorn 0755 lau www-data -
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPass /static/ !
ProxyPass /media/ !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/

</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
```

After restarting my apache, I get 403 at http://127.0.0.1/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8000
```

Any ideas?

I am on Ubuntu 17.04

**EDIT:**

I see some python processes running but not sure if it is correct or not:

```
$ ps -wef | grep python
root      2418     1  0 06:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/apt-xapian-index/update-apt-xapian-index-dbus
lau      25488 28678  0 23:49 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
lau      30605     1  0 18:30 ?        00:00:02 /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/python /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp.sock helloapp.wsgi:application
lau      30609 30605  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/python /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp.sock helloapp.wsgi:application
lau      30610 30605  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/python /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp.sock helloapp.wsgi:application
lau      30612 30605  0 18:30 ?        00:00:00 /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/python /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp.sock helloapp.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, and OP may have resolved the issue, but as far as I can see, you have started Gunicorn on port 8000, and the told apache to listen to the same port. Since two applications are listening on the same port, that probably creates the conflict. Judging by the output of you processes, gunicorn is already running. It will be enough to remove `Listen 8000` from apache configuration file, and restart apache again. This should resolve the problem.